# C# - This Coe is showing that "Please Recheck the CNIC" instead of showing "Account has been deleted"

Tags: c#

I have tried to delete a record from database on the basis of CNIC no. Record is successfully deleting. But neither done is changing to true nor the Message is displaying as "Account has been deleted". The message which is showing is that "Please Recheck the CNIC".

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any specific reason for `ExecuteReader()` in this scenario to execute a `delete` query. It is very very dangerous usage of concatenated queries for delete. I suggest you to use parameterization here to execute the above query. The code will be like the following:

```
string strQuery = "Delete from [AirlineTicketReservation].[dbo].[Traveller_Info] Where CNIC = @CNIC";      
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@CNIC", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = mtxtCNIC.Text;
   int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(rowsAffected > 0)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Account has been deleted.");
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Please Recheck the CNIC, it is not existing", "Failed");
   }
}
```

Update:

I think It is not necessary to check of existence before deleting, Sice we are using `ExecuteNonQuery()` here to execute, which will returns the number of rows affected. if no rows were deleted means the return value will be `0` based on that you can display message.

Comment: But I have to evaluate if the entered CNIC exist in database or not. How can I evaluate that in your way.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will return number of rows effected. If it is 1 then you can validate it exists. If 0 it means CNIC is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Use two queries one select and one delete. **You should refer tutorials for such problems.**

```
    try
    {                
        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "Select CNIC from [AirlineTicketReservation].[dbo].[Traveller_Info] Where CNIC = '" + mtxtCNIC.Text + "'";
        string strDeleteQuery = "Select CNIC from [AirlineTicketReservation].[dbo].[Traveller_Info] Where CNIC = '" + mtxtCNIC.Text + "'";

        SqlDataReader reader;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            cnic = reader["CNIC"].ToString();
            if (mtxtCNIC.Text == cnic)
            {
                SqlCommand delCommand = new SqlCommand(strDeleteQuery, conn);
                delCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                done = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Account has been deleted.");
                                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    if (!done)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Recheck the CNIC", "Failed");
    }
```

Comment: Its really expensive `= '" + mtxtCNIC.Text + "'"`